# Editing an array not working in a for-loop

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm working with a list that contains several nested arrays as elements. Each array represents a set of points to be plotted as a frame in an animated scatter plot. Each frame contains the previous frame as a subset, plus a random number of new points so that in the animation, the scatter plot grows in number of points, but old points remain in place.

The point color and size are stored as information in these arrays, and I'm trying to edit them so that, each frame, the points from the 5 most recent rendered frames are highlighted.

However, when I actually try implement the highlighting, the changes to the list don't seem to persist out of my for loop. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on here?

Sample snippet:

```
newFrames = frames.copy()
# n x 1 list of 2-d arrays representing frames

# the leading 5 frames are highlighted
for i in range(5):
    newFrames[i][:,2] = 1   #color set to black
    newFrames[i][:,3] = 100 #size set to 100

# all succeeding frames have the most recently added data highlighted
for i in range(5,len(newFrames)):
    newFrames[i][:,2] = 0.3
    newFrames[i][:,3] = 2

    # points from most recently added 5 frames are to be highlighted
    j = len(newFrames[i]) - len(newFrames[i-5])

    # highlighting
    newFrames[i][-j:,2] = 1
    newFrames[i][-j:,3] = 100

    # all other points are made small and dim
    newFrames[i][:-j,2] = 0.3 #color set to grey
    newFrames[i][:-j,3] = 2   #size set to 2

    print(newFrames[i][:,2:])

    '''
    Sample output
    [[   0.3    2. ]
    [   0.3    2. ]
    [   0.3    2. ]
    [   0.3    2. ]
    [   0.3    2. ]
    [   1.   100. ]
    [   1.   100. ]
    [   1.   100. ]
    [   1.   100. ] 
    [   1.   100. ]]
    '''
print(newFrames[i][:,2:])

'''
Sample output: what went wrong?
[[   0.3    2. ]
[   0.3    2. ]
[   0.3    2. ]
[   0.3    2. ]
[   0.3    2. ]
[   0.3    2. ]
[   0.3    2. ]
[   0.3    2. ]
[   0.3    2. ]
[   0.3    2. ]]
'''
```

Comment: What is `frames`?  List, array?  What shape?  I'm a bit suspicious of the `newFrames[i][...] = ` expressions.  If you aren't careful the `newFrames[i]` will be a copy, and the assignment modifies that copy, not the original.  I'm not saying that's what's happening here, but be careful.

Comment: good point. I think the problem might lie in the strange way I've defined `frames`. It's built like this:

    `frames = []; for i in range(10): frames.append(np.zeros((i, 2))`

ie. it's a python list containing elements of type np.ndarray, all of different sizes. Maybe I'll just have to restructure the entire thing entirely.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the way my array was organized was causing tons of problems when trying to change anything in it.

Originally, it was organized like this:

```
frames = []
for i in range(10):
    frames.append(np.random.random((i, 4)))
```

For some reason, editing the elements of the arrays stored in `frames` didn't change them in frames themselves.

I solved the problem by building `frames` as

```
frames = np.random.random((10,10,4))
for i in range(10):
    frames[i,i:]=-9999 #placeholder empty value
```